# Dynamically applying a class to a button unable to do click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two div of width 100% absolutely positioned side by side. On clicking a button I want to slide it to left. Then on clicking on same button I want it to come back to its normal position.

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vz9Hj/)

The first part works fine, but I am not able to slide it back. The 2nd part of the jQuery code does not work. Can anyone please tell me the reason why its not working and how to make it work

```
<div class="about-deals">
<span class="view-tomorrow-deal">View Tomorrow Deals</span>
</div>
<div class="deals-image-wrapper">
    <div class="deal-container">
        <div class="today-deals">
        </div>
        <div class="tomorrow-deals">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really the way to create toggle functionality.
When you attach an event handler, that event handler is attached to any element matching the given selector at that time, changing the class later does not remove the event handler or make event handlers executed on pageload magically start working, *unless* they are delegated, but that makes very little sense here.

Just toggle the functionality in the same click handler, if needed use a flag etc.

```
$('.view-tomorrow-deal').click(function (event) {
    $(this).text(function(_,txt) {
        return txt == 'View Tomorrow Deals' ? 'View Today Deals' : 'View Tomorrow Deals';
    });

    $('.deal-container').animate({
        left: $('.deal-container').position().left === 0 ? '-100%' : '0%'
    }, 1000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vz9Hj/5/)

Answer (score 2):

try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vz9Hj/1/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.view-tomorrow-deal', function(event) {
        $(this).removeClass('view-tomorrow-deal');
        $(this).addClass('view-today-deal');
        $(this).text('View Today Deals');
        $('.deal-container').animate({left: '-100%'}, 1000);
    });
$(document).on('click', '.view-today-deal', function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('view-today-deal');
        $(this).addClass('view-tomorrow-deal');
        $(this).text('View Tomorrow Deals');
        $('.deal-container').animate({left: '0%'}, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try  jQuery toggle

```
   $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
   // Animation complete.

   });
 });
```

or
    $("#book").toggle("slide");

Link : https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

for slide effect

Stack link : [slideToggle JQuery right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271169/slidetoggle-jquery-right-to-left)